# Key has no data from subclass of PFUser with reference pointer field

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I need to update the current user and refetch every time the App launches so that I can grasp the most updated version of user object instead of using the one cached on the disk.

```
User.current()?.fetchInBackground(block: { (user, error) in
       //simply using a  fetchInBackground won't fetch the entire reference field store in 
      // the user collection. In the case of using PFQuery, we could simply include the key for  
      // reference field.
})
```

Do I have to do extra fetches for all those reference field and then update the current user's filed correspondingly?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch only returns the data that is stored in your database. For a pointer, that is just a basic JSON object specifying it's a pointer, the class name, and the objectId of that object. In order to return this data, you'll instead want to use a Parse Query and include the field that you want. Include works with dot notation, so you could do something like `objectAQuery.include("objectB.objectC")` which will include all of the data of objectC stored as a pointer on objectB.  That will not include all of objectB's data, if I'm not mistaken, though I can't say with certainty.

Finally, use `query.get()` to get an object with a specific objectId. This will throw an error if the object does not exist, though, so make sure you handle that appropriately. You could also use query equalTo on the objectId then call `query.first()`, but `get` would be more recommended.

Comment: Note - my examples used JS, not Swift, so the function names may be different, but equivalents definitely exist in both SDKs.

Comment: I know I can use query to get the corresponding data, but can I do it in one pass? The problem is that the PFUser is cached and stored in the disk, every time I launch the app, I expect to update the current user from the remote database instead of using the one in the cache. Usually we use fetchIfNeed to update the receiver to a new value, not sure how it's done in the case when your object has pointer fields

Comment: fetchIfNeeded doesn't do what it appears you think it is doing.  fetchIfNeeded will only fetch if, say, you called fetch on an objectA that has a pointer to an objectB, and you call fetchIfNeeded on objectB. Or, if you create a new PFObject, and set it's ID manually, then call fetchIfNeeded.  Fetch if needed will never fetch a previously fetched object. As soon as the object is fetched, the boolean that determines whether or not fetchIfNeeded will fetch is flipped. It does not fetch whenever there is new information.

Comment: And yes, let's say objectA has pointers to objectB and objectC, and objectB has a pointer to objectD. You could do something similar to `objectAQuery.include("objectB").include("objectC").include("objectB.objectD");`, then `objectAQuery.get(objectId, {useMasterKey:true})` and you'll basically be fetching the objectA object with id objectId and all of its data, and the objects it points to data.